# Node.js code does not execute

Tags: node.js, nodes

I have written some Node.js code but when I run `node index.js` in my terminal it's just blank. My Node script does not even log to the console after creating the server or is responding with my `index.html` file. I even tried changing all 'req' and 'res' to 'request' and 'response'. Here's my code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlparse = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

http.createServer(function(request, response){
 console.log('listening on port 8080');
 app.on('request', function(request, response){
   response.sendFile('./index.html');
  });
 app.post('/auth', urlparse, function(request, response){
   var user = request.body.user;
   var pass = request.body.pass;
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Pleas help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Anything inside the `http.createserver();` does not execute because I tried logging another sentence outside the `http.createServer();` and it logged!

Comment: You do realize you can't run NodeJS in a Stack Snippet because it's server sided javascript, right?

Comment: Yes I do. Well I am a newbie to node but come on not that bad.......

Comment: So why did you put in a snippet?

Comment: Well... I don't know how whatever that is got there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and try the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlparse = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.on('request', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile('./index.html');
});
app.post('/auth', urlparse, function (request, response) {
    var user = request.body.user;
    var pass = request.body.pass;
});

// Bind createServer with app:
http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function (request, response) {
    console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

I expect that this should work for you.

Update:

The method mentioned, while works, has become outdated.
the recommended method is:

```
app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

Using this method allows you to skip requiring http.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked Thank you for such a quick response!!